# Easy Regex on Apache Logs

Tags: regular-expression, logs, apache-httpd

I'm struggling to create a regex for Apache logs. It's for `ignoreregex` on `Fail2ban`.

I'd really like to be able to put something like `/house` to catch all files in that directory or `/house/jonross.html` specifically to match just that HTML file. The log format I'm using is below.

The field is the one where `/city/index.html` is in this example.

`66-121-89-14.domain.com - - [14/Apr/2011:14:47:05 +0100] "GET /city/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2577 "http://www.domain.com/referrer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16"`

Can a regex whizz please help ?

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of trial and hour, in case it helps someone else, this will ignore any directory after the slash after GET with these words:

`ignoreregex = .*\"GET \/(city|house|anything).*`

Comment: You might want to match `HEAD` and other HTTP methods, using `(GET|HEAD|...)`